# Mongodb connection shows inappropriate number on mongo console.

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I am using Mongodb 3.2 version. Using Spring's org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate and com.mongodb.Mongo for mongodb connections, queries and aggregation.

```
    Software Configuration:
  spring-core 4.1.6.RELEASE, spring-data-mongodb 1.8.2.RELEASE, mongo-java-driver 3.1.0, spring-context 4.1.6.RELEASE, Tomcat 8.
```

It looks like mongodb connections are not closing properly. At some time mongodb console shows 10 connections still active. Other than my webapp I use Robomongo tool to check mongodb data. So it should be only two connections at any point of time.

After i shutdown my tomcat and Robomongo, still there are 4 connections active and also at some point it had peaked to 10 with tomcat and Robomongo running.

Logs:

```
        2016-07-16T12:29:12.835+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=792 port=27017 dbpath=C:\mongodata 64-bit host=DESKTOP-SFNL93Q
        2016-07-16T12:29:12.956+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
        2016-07-16T12:29:12.960+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.6
        2016-07-16T12:29:12.961+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 05552b562c7a0b3143a729aaa0838e558dc49b25
        2016-07-16T12:29:12.962+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1p-fips 9 Jul 2015
        2016-07-16T12:29:12.964+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
        2016-07-16T12:29:12.965+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
        2016-07-16T12:29:12.966+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
        2016-07-16T12:29:12.967+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
        2016-07-16T12:29:12.968+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
        2016-07-16T12:29:12.969+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
        2016-07-16T12:29:12.970+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "C:\mongodata" } }
        2016-07-16T12:29:12.993+0530 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in C:\mongodata created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
        2016-07-16T12:29:12.999+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=4G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
        2016-07-16T12:29:14.717+0530 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
        2016-07-16T12:29:14.717+0530 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory 'C:/mongodata/diagnostic.data'
        2016-07-16T12:29:14.744+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
        2016-07-16T12:33:51.795+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53065 #1 (1 connection now open)
        2016-07-16T12:41:16.247+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53243 #2 (2 connections now open)
        2016-07-16T12:41:58.268+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53253 #3 (3 connections now open)
        2016-07-16T12:41:58.318+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53254 #4 (4 connections now open)
        2016-07-16T12:42:02.864+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53255 #5 (5 connections now open)
        2016-07-16T12:42:02.922+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53256 #6 (6 connections now open)
        2016-07-16T12:42:04.920+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53257 #7 (7 connections now open)
        2016-07-16T12:42:04.958+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53258 #8 (8 connections now open)
        2016-07-16T12:46:51.214+0530 I NETWORK  [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:53065 (7 connections now open)
        2016-07-16T12:46:51.216+0530 I NETWORK  [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:53243 (7 connections now open)
        2016-07-16T12:48:51.768+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53378 #9 (7 connections now open)
        2016-07-16T12:51:07.622+0530 I NETWORK  [conn9] end connection 127.0.0.1:53378 (6 connections now open)
        2016-07-16T12:53:27.581+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53403 #10 (7 connections now open)
        2016-07-16T12:54:20.400+0530 I NETWORK  [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:53253 (6 connections now open)
        2016-07-16T12:54:20.401+0530 I NETWORK  [conn4] end connection 127.0.0.1:53254 (6 connections now open)
        2016-07-16T12:55:38.285+0530 I NETWORK  [conn10] end connection 127.0.0.1:53403 (4 connections now open)
```

Comment: Try to check those ports which logs 'claim' to have a mongo connection alive.

Comment: You are aware of the fact that the Java Driver maintains a connection _pool_?

Comment: yes i am aware of connection pool. But my doubt was even after tomcat container is shutdown, why still four of the connections as alive.